# Using process.env in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

I am trying to dynamically assign the IP address based if it is a production or development environment.

The react is served via a Django app.

The `.env` is in the root project of the react app at the same level as the package.json file

```
REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL=127.0.0.1:8000
```

I call it this way

```
require('dotenv').config()

const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL
console.log(API_URL)
```

I get the following error in the console:

```
main.js:83 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.config (main.js:83)
    at eval (index.js:13)
    at Object../src/index.js (main.js:700)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:2244)
    at main.js:2489
    at main.js:2491
```

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

**EXTRA INFO:**

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --entry ./src/index.js --output-path ./static/",
    "prod": "webpack --mode production --entry ./src/index.js --output-path ./static/"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.3.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.55.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.3.0"
  }
}
```

React is set up using Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install --silent\
    && npm install react-scripts@4.0.3 -g --silent
```

I then start react using the following

```
(cd frontend/src && npm run dev)
```

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {

    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            "os": false,
            "fs": false,
            "tls": false,
            "net": false,
            "path": false,
            "zlib": false,
            "http": false,
            "https": false,
            "stream": false,
            "crypto": false,
            "crypto-browserify": require.resolve('crypto-browserify'), //if you want to use this module also don't forget npm i crypto-browserify
        }
    },

    module: {


        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 8192,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: are you using custom webpack.config.js ?

Comment: @benjaminc yes I am using that, and added it to the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `dotenv-webpack` and then everything should work ;-)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack

### .env

REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL=127.0.0.1:8000

---

```
const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL
console.log(API_URL)
```

Comment: @MarioGB I am sorry this did not work. I update the question with dotenv installed.

Comment: @JosephAdam Cool buddy, I'll try to figure it out :-P

Comment: @JosephAdam Please try to use the .env instead of .env.development :-)

Comment: I am sorry that did not work either. I updated the question where I expanded my webpack.config.js. It is custom served via Django

Comment: dotenv-webpack worked :)

Comment: @JosephAdam Congrats ! I Am happy to see that :D ;-)

Comment: Thanks, can you edit your answer to that so I am able to select it as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

and before that you should install as follows:

```
# with npm
npm install dotenv

# or with Yarn
yarn add dotenv
```

and then you can use...

```
process.env.REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL
```

Comment: `require('dotenv').config()`, you mean add this one to the same script as `Images.js?` on top?

Comment: this means you have to install the dotenv package. In your docker file after the other npm installations you should add: npm install dotenv
Then in your Images.js code you add (after the includes) the line: require('dotenv').config()

Comment: I am sorry that did not work. I updated the question where I expanded my webpack.config.js. It is custom served via Django